# Sharepoint Online list Threshold error for more than 5 items in the list

Tags: sharepoint

I am fetching the list from the different SharePoint  as we were not facing this problem initially now we are facing this for for fetching the list items.

public Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection GetListItems(string listName, string query = "")
{
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)48 | (SecurityProtocolType)192 | (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
List listResult = _context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery { ViewXml = query };
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection result = listResult.GetItems(camlQuery);

```
    _context.Load(result);
    _context.ExecuteQuery();

    return result;
}
```

<View><RowLimit>1000</RowLimit><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='TravelForm' /><Value Type='Lookup'>47161</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Source' /><Value Type='Text'>Travel Center</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query></View>

The above method giving us the  error exceeded Treshould limit.

can anyone guide here , for some other lists  its working only for some specific list we are doing in batches but the above code is not working for some specific lists . we did checked all the list settings  nothing cahnged for some of the lists but these lists are giving error.

Please let me know anyone finds any solution for this .

I am fetching the list from the different SharePoint  as we were not facing this problem initially now we are facing this for for fetching the list items.

public Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection GetListItems(string listName, string query = "")
{
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)48 | (SecurityProtocolType)192 | (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
List listResult = _context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery { ViewXml = query };
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection result = listResult.GetItems(camlQuery);

```
    _context.Load(result);
    _context.ExecuteQuery();

    return result;
}
```

<View><RowLimit>1000</RowLimit><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='TravelForm' /><Value Type='Lookup'>47161</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Source' /><Value Type='Text'>Travel Center</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query></View>

The above method giving us the  error exceeded Treshould limit.

can anyone guide here , for some other lists  its working only for some specific list we are doing in batches but the above code is not working for some specific lists . we did checked all the list settings  nothing cahnged for some of the lists but these lists are giving error.

Please let me know anyone finds any solution for this .

Answer (score 0):

We faced similiar issues, the threshold might be reached at some server side query operation. Please check list view settings like filters and ordering, it could also help to create a new view without filtering / ordering and query that one.

Do you use indices on your list columns? This also impacts the threshold.